# cant hear audio from any apps other than internet browser xubuntu pulseaudio

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, realtek, speakers

I can't get audio working, pulseaudio seems to detect built in analog speakers but can't hear anything even on max volume. tried reinstalling just for pulseaudio to disappear from my taskbar and still not working, alsamixer shows my soundcard but also cant hear audio after putting it on max volume, speakers are not muted and microphone won't even show up on pulseaudio nor any app (same goes with the speakers) but only on my installed os as they work flawlessly on any os like live ubuntu etc but not on the one on my disk. is there any way to get audio working again without having to reinstall the whole os all over again? as these are realtek speakers i also tried downloading their linux drivers from 2018 but can't even get them to compile as they keep throwing a linux kernel source not found error :(

Comment: Please complete your question with the output of `pacmd list-source-outputs`